# How to create a meaningful dynamic property?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0

The fictional example here. Suppose I designed a class named IODevice. This class already implements a structure that allows me to use it in the following way:

```
        IODevice dio = new IODevice();

        try
        {
            dio.Pin["IsBirdInCageSensor"].Set();
            dio.Pin["KillBird"].Get();
            //dio.Pin["NonExistant"].Set(); //exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

Pins here are a series of IO lines in a digital IO box that can go high (1) or low (0).

I would like to use dynamic to call it in the following way:

```
        dio.Pins.KillBird.Get();
```

My IO device class looks like this right now, and as you will notice, I haven't advanced much on how to implement the dynamic interface, except for using the dynamic keyword.

```
class IODevice
{
    public IODevice()
    {
        pin = new PinCollection();
        pin.Add(new Pin("IsBirdInCageSensor", 0));
        pin.Add(new Pin("KillBird", 1));
    }

    private PinCollection pin;
    public PinCollection Pin { get { return pin; } }

    public dynamic Pins { get; private set; }
}
```

The second question is: what are the disadvantages of using such design? (apart from the lack of hard type checking - which I don't have anyways)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to carry on using your existing `PinCollection` type, then PinCollection needs to implement [IDynamicMetaObjectProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider%28VS.100%29.aspx).  Then Pins would return the same PinCollection as Pin, but because it was typed as dynamic would allow the `obj.Pins.KillBird` syntax (and your GetMetaObject implementation would translate this into dictionary accesses on PinCollection).

If you can change your implementation, then you can instead use the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28VS.100%29.aspx) class:

```
private ExpandoObject _pins;
public dynamic Pins { get { return _pins; } }
```

ExpandoObject is basically a dictionary that already has a metaobject that translates dynamic property accesses into dictionary accesses.  Note that in this case you would have to get rid of the strong-typed PinCollection, or figure out some way to synchronise the two: you don't want different pin data stored in the two places.

Comment: @itowlson: Good suggestion, and +1 for mentioning ExpandoObject.
@Padu: Checkout the C# example here[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(VS.100).aspx], might help.

Comment: Padu: there's an extraneous ] on the end of KMan's link.  Just delete that.  But I think it goes to the same place as the ExpandoObject link in the answer body.

Comment: Just couple more links with examples:
http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx (ExpandoObject) and http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject.aspx (DynamicObject)